# Finding the volume of circular cone.

Tags: calculus

I´m trying to find the Volume of a Circular right cone. The height is 3 units (y-axis) and the radius is 2 units (x-axis).

So, if i Want to find the volume I have to write a equation above in terms of "y", for this situation. Right? 
The question ask me the equation that generates the solid. I have found x=(2/3)y. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain geometrically the circular right cone by rotating the region bounded by the lines $y=\frac23 x$, $x=0$ and $x=3$. Using the formula for the volume of a solid of revolution, you must calculate $$V=\int_{0}^{3}\pi\left(\frac23 x\right)^2dx$$ which is pretty easy.

Comment: But  in this case, Am I not find only the volume of a oblique cone? I thinking  that i have to integrate the same expression above, but in this case changing the limits of integration from 0 to 2 and the function between brackets.

Comment: No, you don't. Maybe the animation of the cone [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/cone.html) helps you to see what that integral means. And be careful, if you do from $0$ to $2$ then you are calculating the volume of the cone of height $2$ and radius $4/3$. Note that when $x=3$ (the height of the conus) then $y=2$ (the radius).

Comment: Remember that the height is 3 units (y-axis) and the radius is 2 units (x-axis).

Comment: Remember that a line is "essentially" the same line if you rotate it. Your conus is the same conus I'm telling you, with a $90$ degrees rotation.